# How to select whole rectangle around item in listview?

Tags: c#, listview

I want to select whole rectangle around item in listview(C#) not just text
like this ->

[image: common selection rectangle]

I want like this ->

[image: whole rect selection]

Comment: any relevant code you can show? :)

Comment: This might involve having to respond to the [DrawItem event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.drawitem(v=vs.110).aspx). Be sure to read that carefully if you decide to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is the the `ListView` to [`FullRowSelect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.fullrowselect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
 listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
```

> **true** if clicking an item selects the item and all its subitems; **false**
>   if clicking an item selects only the item itself. The default is
>   **false**.
>
> The FullRowSelect property has no effect unless the View property of
>   the ListView control is set to Details. The FullRowSelect property is
>   typically used when a ListView displays items with many subitems and
>   it is important to be able to see selected items when the item text is
>   not visible due to horizontal scrolling of the control's contents.